# Razor App_Web_xxxxxxxx.pdb not generated on my VM (admin), but generated on my PC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2017, razor-pages

VS2017, .NET 4.7. I generate a sample ASP.NET (.NET framework) MVC project with the template in "new project". I use IISExpress. On my PC (Windows 8) the razor pdb files are generated in:

C:\Users\xxxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\2\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\1e1a228d\9ada4f02\   App_Web_xxxxxxxx.pdb

The following break point works:

[image]

On my VM, Windows server 2012 R2, as admin, the App_Web_xxxxxxxx.dll files are generated, but there no pdb files with them.

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\ff03b586\aba173c3\App_Web_xxxxxxxx.dll

How can I generate the debugging info on the VM? (Same version of VS2017). (C# break points work)

More tests:
I generate a vanilla ASP.NET CORE MVC project:
[image]

But with .NET Framework:
[image]

Comment: Apparently if you are admin on a server, C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework..., will be used. If you are not admin on a PC, C:\Users\me\AppData\Local will be used. This can be changed in the web.config:  <compilation ... tempDirectory="D:\Temp\Test" debug="true"/>. Still no *.pdb for App_Web_dbiipr41.dll

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I am now able to generate the missing pdb files manually with the following command:

```
aspnet_compiler.exe -v / -p D:\Temp\Code\VS2017\TestRazor\WebApplication2\WebApplication2 D:\Temp\Test -d
```

I bind the destination Test folder in IIS, attach the debugger, and *yes*, breakpoints are now being hit.

I must now figure out why none of the MVC projects (some legacy) compiled in debug on this VM are afflicted with this problem.